# Create WooCommerce order from product list -- bulk actions

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to be able to manually create an order in the backend of WooCommerce by selecting specific products. A new order would be created with the selected products.

Is it possible to add a "create order" function to the "bulk actions" part of the page?

[Please see this image for further explanation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akTZa.png)

Thank you!

Comment: do you have some code to share regarding your question?

Comment: Sorry, Olympiloutre I am not very experienced and just don't know where to start with the code for this. If you have any suggestions that would be great.